# Unity For playermovement with imageFix

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I run my unity project and playerMovement Starts then image is also moving with player...I want to stop the image moving with playerMovement.

Im sharing the drive link where I uploaded the video of problem.

drive link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1g-8FrnSuSRdWFKQWtiWHlPN3M?resourcekey=0-W0A1w2KqXZR1WaCAYhKfdA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ooof. Video in your google drive has no file extension, I renamed it "*.mp4" but the image is strangely stretched, also you filmed it sideways, in portrait mode... I had to turn my head. Then, there is this noise...

Can you at least record a proper video? And maybe upload it to imgur? It's just Drag&Drop - no account needed...

---

So, is the "linkedIn Logo" image attatched to your player or camera? I mean, is it a child of that? That would explain why it moves with it...

Comment: I'm not attached with player this image but why it still moving

Comment: can you please help me to fix this

Comment: Is that image a UI element? Either make it a Sprite in your scene, or put the UI Canvas to "world space" or "Screenspace camera".